# HOw to upload large content html under an array in monogodb through cmd

Tags: mongodb

I have an structure like this:

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5f31183723406c2ad8b72e7e"),
 content: ["<h3 class=\"ql-align-justify\">Hello world<h3>"]
}
```

Now When update content field through cmd and replace the content with large content then on cmd, mongodb will not fully copy the string and generates error
**uncaught exception: SyntaxError: "" literal not terminated before end of script :**

On my development machine I have a robo mongo GUI so I will directly update the content and things are fine.

But on server I have to do all this things through terminal and I am facing the error.

Command which I am using is

```
db.CollectionName.updateOne({_id: ObjectId('5f31183723406c2ad8b72e7e')}, {$set: {content: ["here my large content of html"]}})
```

Comment: Sounds like you're not escaping the double quotes in your update statement?